# How to use SiriKit for sending data using Web Service?

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I am exploring SiriKit and I want to use it for sending data to web server. Basically, I want to send some data whenever user says "Hey Siri, send data using SomeApplication". Here 'SomeApplication' is the name of my app. I googled a bit, but I came to know that I can only use the intents given by SiriKit, I can't create my own. Please help me if there is some way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s true that you can’t create your own intents but there’s a trick that you can play. You can use the Messaging intent and instead of sending text message, you can make your service call from there. 
In the IntentHandler.swift file, modify the code of resolveRecipients method to create a custom contact. This would result in showing a messaging UI but would skip the step of asking for recipient.  Instead, Siri would directly ask for the message that you would receive in resolveContent method. Get it from there and call your web service. As simple as that.

Here's the code

```
func resolveRecipients(for intent: INSendMessageIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INPersonResolutionResult]) -> Void) {

               let resolutionResults = [INPersonResolutionResult.success(with: INPerson.init(personHandle: INPersonHandle.init(value: "Raw", type: .unknown), nameComponents: PersonNameComponents.init(), displayName: "Raw", image: INImage.init(), contactIdentifier: "Raw", customIdentifier: "Raw"))]

        completion(resolutionResults)
    }
```

For detailed example, you can checkout this [Git Repo for SiriKitDemo](https://github.com/pallavtrivedi03/SiriKit-Demo)

Comment: It worked like a charm, exactly what I wanted. Moderator please accept this as correct answer. Thanks a ton @pallavtrivedi